# select count in mysql on 2 fields to get aggregated result

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql Table.

```
+----+----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | transaction_id |  user_id  |    book_id    |    purchase_date    |
+----+----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| 52 | bq4ren25a8w0   | ABC_00002 | xxxx951410361 | 2017-04-25 12:30:18 |
| 66 | j4ax039ilc00   | ABC_00260 | xxxx951410392 | 2017-04-25 12:30:18 |
| 67 | s2a57kp4g000   | ABC_00260 | xxxx951410361 | 2017-06-05 12:28:56 |
| 68 | h4z4h80ts000   | ABC_00260 | xxxx951410415 | 2017-06-07 12:47:24 |
| 69 | 2bt7ipsf9sy3   | ABC_00262 | xxxx951410392 | 2017-06-05 13:25:10 |
| 70 | x0rlwhm00000   | ABC_00264 | xxxx951410392 | 2017-06-09 14:23:08 |
+----+----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I need a result whic is group by book_id + purchase_date such that

```
+---------------+---------------------+-------+
|    book_id    |    purchase_date    | count |
+---------------+---------------------+-------+
| xxxx951410361 | 2017-04-25 12:30:18 |    10 |
| xxxx951410392 | 2017-06-05 14:27:19 |    12 |
+---------------+---------------------+-------+
```

I dont have much exposure in mysql, I just tried

```
Select Count(book_id) as book_id, purchase_date 
FROM tbl_name 
GROUP BY book_id, purchase_date
```

Its not working.

Need some help

Comment: Just add `book_id` to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  It looks like you're grouping on a `DateTime` which would mean your count would be everyone that purchased `book_id` at the EXACT same time.  So I'm assuming you have each row with count of 1?

Comment: How do you get a count of `10` from the sample data you showed?

Comment: @barmar , the answer shown is just a sample of what I required. Its just hard coded in SO. I dont know how to get that result in mysql.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're really trying to do if the desired result doesn't match the sample input. What's wrong with the query you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DATE** to group the purchases by days.

```
SELECT book_id,COUNT(book_id),DATE(purchase_date) AS pdate FROM book_sales GROUP BY book_id,pdate;
```

If you want to know how many books were sold on a specific day, you can use:

```
SELECT DATE(purchase_date) AS purchase_date,COUNT(DATE(purchase_date)) AS books FROM book_sales GROUP BY DATE(purchase_date);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cde14/6

Comment: This will group together purchases on the same day of different months. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: This is what I want. Is there any way to get Total numbers of book_id sold group by purchase_date.(not required individual packages)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, hope you will get what you need.

```
SELECT book_id, purchase_date,COUNT(purchase_date) as count
FROM book_sales 
GROUP BY purchase_date;
```